# How to demonstrate that a document cited by law must be also open access?

Tags: legal

The **"Principle of Access to Information"** (PAI) expressed in the legislation of many countries — usually countries with some ["Access to Information Act"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_to_Information_Act) or [freedom of information laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_information_laws_by_country) —, apply to any *law document* or "[obligation rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_obligations) records", stated by the [State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(polity)). In some countries the obligation of law-publicity and no-payment for information is reinforced by the  [*Ignorantia juris non excusat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignorantia_juris_non_excusat).

The question here is

> How to use PAI for (legally) demonstrate that any other norm or document, **citaed** by a *law document*, must be submited also to the PAI?

This situation is similar to the "contamination by use" of a share-alike licenced document (ex. [CC by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)), but here the mechanism is ***"contamination by citation"***.

---

#### Notes and examples:

This is a question for use with any democratic country where we can start with the hypothesis that  *“country's law has no copyright”*. So, the question is: *how to* (!?) convince citizens, the government and the court that *"any document cited by law also has no copyright"*?

Examples where the problem was recognized by court:

- in the Brazil, before 2004, some *[construction process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction#Construction_processes) law* was obligating the law-reader to read (cited) *payed [technical standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_standard)*. After 2004 a [juridical decision made free](http://www.pessoacomdeficiencia.gov.br/app/normas-da-abnt/termo-de-ajustamento-de-conduta) these standards.
- [coherent use of postcodes](http://index.okfn.org/dataset/postcodes/): many laws and rules of countries (any, like Brazil, Croatia, Finland, or Uruguay) *obligate citizens to use postcodes*, and cite explicitly the [postcode standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code) in law.   Finland and Uruguay are countries where obligation is coherent with freedom of access (to postcode databases).

Example where the problem (of no oficial answering of this question) exist:

- [coherent use of postcodes](http://index.okfn.org/dataset/postcodes/): ... explanation above...   Finland and Uruguay are coherent ... But Brazil and Croatia are not. 
  In Brazil the [postcodes are protected by Authors' rights](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63936/4186), but is a country with strong Access to Information Acts, etc. so is possible to create opennes/coherence by using  some PAI principle.

Comment: are you asking for precedent? or an example of how to display/enforce it? i know this is the battle brewing between municode and u.s. localities that use it to display government documents

Comment: @albert thanks, two issues... (1) yes I'm looking for precedent or any other kind of "juri decision" or "law change", in response to the "contamination by citation".   (2) I do not known Municode Corporation, but seems a good case, where govern transferred publishing rights to municode ... them municode enforced citizens to pay for the "contaminated documents" (supposing that in USA documents cited by law must be free and Open Access)... do you have a link for it?

Comment: this addresses the problem, not the corporation specifically, though it mentions others: http://www.govtech.com/DC-Takes-an-Open-Data-Approach-to-Muni-Code.html

Comment: @albert Hum... it is embarrassing for "USA as a democracy model" ;-)   your link say that *"A number of states and localities place a copyright on the actual published copy of their laws, and also outsource the code's upkeep to a private company"*.  This is a reality for USA-law? There are no ["US-government official gazette"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_gazette), with free access to citizens?

Comment: If anyone was involved in such a decision, I suspect it would be Carl Malamud : https://public.resource.org/

Comment: @Joe, thanks! Carl sent  me fast comments. He have a very interesting video and article at https://public.resource.org/edicts/  ... A good summary of Carl's position,  about the  general subject of this kind of question, is **“the law has no copyright”**.

Comment: Hum... even with a bounty, no answer... so, let's do a proposal :-) https://github.com/okfn/opendefinition/issues/114

Comment: "In any democratic country we can start with the hypothesis that “country's law has no copyright”." I think this is a major problem to begin with - it's simply not the case that this is always true for all countries (or all parts of all countries).

Comment: @Andrew, thanks (!). I edited, check if now is correct. It is a "working hypothesis"...

Comment: @PeterKrauss here's another one to watch in the US: the state of Georgia is suing Public Resource for posting state laws http://ia801504.us.archive.org/1/items/gov.uscourts.gand.218354/gov.uscourts.gand.218354.docket.html

Comment: Hi @albert, thanks! hum... I am not an expert, how to interpret this "logs"? I think [this PDF](http://www.archive.org/download/gov.uscourts.gand.218354/gov.uscourts.gand.218354.1.2.pdf) is the only human-readable ;-)   But the document have "Filed 07/21/15", and Wikipedia says that [Malamud’s campaign to become US Public Printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Malamud#Malamud.E2.80.99s_campaign_to_become_US_Public_Printer)  is 2009... Do you have more links about? .... Perhaps [can help in the Wikipedia's discussion about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Carl_Malamud#UPDATE_2015.3F)

Comment: not really....if you don't mind, email me so we can take this out of comments - jalbertbowden google's email service.